# Plpgsql function convert BigInt to XID and java

Tags: java, postgresql, plpgsql

Sorry if this was already answered, but I couldn't find one myself.

I have a function in plgsql like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION collect_transaction_data(xid) RETURNS TEXT AS
$$
DECLARE
...
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_transactions WHERE my_tx_id = $1) THEN
        -- Do something useful...
        ...
    END IF;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If I write a small function that calls this function from within postgres using the current transaction ID, everything works fine:

```
PERFORM collect_transaction_data(current_tx_id);
```

However, if I try to call the same function from Java, it complains that the function with an integer value doesn't exist (which is the case). I have a code similar to the following:

```
public boolean testCollectTransactionData(BigInteger my_tx_id)
{
  String sql = String.format("SELECT amqp.collect_transaction_data(%s) AS my_result",
                             my_tx_id.toString());
  java.sql.Statement tx_st  = m_oTxDbConnector.getDbConnection().createStatement();
  java.sql.ResultSet tx_rs  = tx_st.executeQuery(sql);
  tx_rs.next();
  String my_result          = tx_rs.getString("my_result");
  ...
}
```

If I use the same approach using an SQL statement, it works just fine (from Java):

```
String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM my_test_table WHERE my_tx_id = %s",
                           my_tx_id.toString());
java.sql.Statement tx_st  = m_oTxDbConnector.getDbConnection().createStatement();
java.sql.ResultSet tx_rs  = tx_st.executeQuery(sql);
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way around it?

Any help is much appreciated,

D.

*PS*. *I couldn't find a better title for this question. Please correct as you see fits.*

Comment: try `collect_transaction_data(%s::xid)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it didn't work: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type integer to xid. Is there a way to do it in plpgsql directly? Tried CAST with no success, but may be I didn't use it correctly?

Comment: I found the following kludge, but I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do. In the plpgsql function above, tuurn it into the following:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION collect_transaction_data(bigint) RETURNS TEXT AS
$$
DECLARE
my_tx_id_from_int xid;
...
BEGIN
    my_tx_id_from_int := $1;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_transactions WHERE my_tx_id = my_tx_id_from_int) THEN
        -- Do something useful...
        ...
    END IF;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Answer (score 1):

Until someone else suggests a better approach the following did work for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION collect_transaction_data(bigint) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
my_tx_id_from_int xid;
...
BEGIN
  my_tx_id_from_int := $1;
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_transactions WHERE my_tx_id = my_tx_id_from_int) THEN
    -- Do something useful...
    ...
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```